# Custom mouse events in backbonejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

What would be a good way of supporting custom mouse events? For example, I currently have:

```
events: {
  "mousedown .canvas-container" : "getPixel",
},
```

But instead of `mousedown`, I would like to create a custom event called `mousedrag` which would be a combination of `mousedown` and `mousemove`. Is there any recommended way of adding such a custom event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Backbone element events are simply jQuery ( or whatever library you use ) events, you might want to use jQuery UI : http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/ . By loading aside with jQuery and Backbone you will have "drag" event, which you could bind in your code, just like any other event :

```
   events: { "drag .canvas-container" : "getPixel" }
```

Of course there is a way to create a custom events in jQuery, but I assume it is a lot of work for the draggable objects and since it is already written with cross-browser support it is better to use jQuery UI.

P.S. jQuery UI is fully customizable, so you can build your own version on the site, which includes the specific methods you want : http://jqueryui.com/download

Comment: Thanks! That seems like a step in the right direction for me. The drag event only registers if I have draggable set on ".canvas-container". Then when I drag, the getPixel function does trigger but .canvas-container starts dragging along with it. 

I'm trying to get the pixel under the mousepointer while the mouse is dragging while keeping the canvas-container in place.

Comment: Well you might want to make a transparent draggable div, with the size of the canvas and on top of it ( z-index manipulation ) and get the pixels of it while dragging ... or I'm not sure if jQuery UI supports something like this ...

Comment: I was able to use the containment property to contain canvas-container so it doesn't move. Not the best solution but it works!